# Three different ways to declare local instance variables within the implementation file - what's the difference

Tags: ios, objective-c

First of all let me start by saying that I searched but I couldn't find the specific answer to my question.

I was under the impression that you needed an interface within the implementation file if you wanted to declare any local instance variable but to my surprise I accidently declared some variables outside the interface and it actually worked.

Can someone explain what would be the differece between the following local variable declarations?

**A:**
This is what I thought was the correct and the only way you could declare local instance variables **within** the implementation file.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
    // local instance variables
    int myInt;
    float myFloat;

}
    // local properties go here
@end

@implementation ViewController

@end
```

**B:**
but, declaring them right below the implementation also worked fine.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{

}

@end

@implementation ViewController
    int myInt;
    float myFloat;
@end
```

**C:**
and also if I add curly braces to the implementation and declare them in there works fine

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{

}

@end

@implementation ViewController
{
    int myInt;
    float myFloat;
}
@end
```

What is the difference between the variable declarations above?

Thanks

Comment: Check [Variable declaration difference in iOS 6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13514642/variable-declaration-difference-in-ios-6)

Comment: **B** mean's their defined as 'class' (global) variables - they are **not** instance variables (as explained by the above link)

Comment: **Quote from Link:**   
`Variables inside brackets directly after the @interface or @implementation are instance variables. These are variables associated with each instance of your class, and thus accessible anywhere in your instance methods.` Very well explained, thanks for the link.

Quick question before this question is voted to be closed since it's partially a duplicate. The only thing left here I think would be the difference between **A** and **C**, both are instance variables but is there really a difference or it's just a matter of preference? Thank you all for the good info.

Comment: @fs_tigre: it's just a matter of preference.